# Getting error: The expression is not a valid conditional expression

Tags: oracle, jpa, jpql

```
Query eWFqery = em.createQuery("SELECT eworkfirm FROM EsafWorkFirms eworkfirm WHERE eworkfirm.feiNum = :feiNumber AND eworkfirm.getEsafWork().getWorkId() IN :workIdList");
        eWFqery.setParameter("feiNumber", firmObj.getFeiNum());
        eWFqery.setParameter("workIdList", workIdList);
```

Please help i am getting the following error.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT eworkfirm FROM 
EsafWorkFirms eworkfirm WHERE eworkfirm.feiNum = :feiNumber AND 
eworkfirm.getEsafWork().getWorkId() IN :workIdList]. 
[52, 136] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this syntax is problematic in [jpql](/questions/tagged/jpql): `getEsafWork().getWorkId()` ...

please try instead (if list contains ids):

```
eworkfirm.esafWork.workId in ...
```

...and if list contains "works", then just:

```
eworkfirm.esafWork in ...
```